# Unauthorized access to User Profile Service web service

Tags: user-profile, user-profile-service, forms-authentication, claims-based-auth, sts

I have two zones for my SP2010 site collection: default (uses Win Auth- claims) and internet (uses FBA to an AD user store).  I have a WP which would call the User Profile Web Service and get some profile data back.  It was working fine until I changed the default zone's authentication method to allow FBA in addition to Win Auth (claims).  Now when I call the USP web service (which is inside an runwithelevatedprivileges block), I get an unauthorized exception.

So, this authentication change seems to have broken my ability to call the UPS web service.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It was working fine until I changed the default zone's authentication method to allow FBA in addition to Win Auth (claims).

Instead of changing the default zone, I think you should have [extended the web application](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg276322%28v=office.14%29.aspx). If you can't switch things back to how they where, I would consider to [restore the web application](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee748647%28v=office.14%29.aspx):

> ## Considerations when restoring a Web application in SharePoint
>
> Consider the following information as you prepare to restore a Web application:
>
> - You can only restore one Web application at a time by using the procedures in this article. However, you can simultaneously restore all the Web applications in the farm by restoring the complete farm.
> - If a Web application uses the object cache, you must manually configure two special user accounts for the Web application after you restore the Web application. For more information about the object cache and how to configure these user accounts, see Configure object cache user accounts.
> - You cannot use SQL Server tools to restore a Web application.
> - When you restore a Web application that is configured to use claims-based authentication, there are additional steps that you must follow after restoring the Web application to restore claims-based authentication.